# Block officeclient.microsoft.com on Office 2016

Tags: microsoft-office, proxy, hosts

We are in a migration process to Win10+Office16 in my company.

In the new system, every time we open any Office application, a proxy pop up appears asking for credentials and we would like to block this in my company.

We tried with the local firewall with a custom rule blocking all traffic to internet from all office executables. It worked but in fact it blocked some other connections that we would like to keep, like the possibility of opening remote documents.

The second try was using the hosts file, C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts.
I just added a line 127.0.0.1 officeclient.microsoft.com

Surprisingly it does not work, simply it is not taken into account by Office.

Could someone explain me why? any other strategy to prevent the popup to appear?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In Office 2016, click File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Privacy Options, clear the selection for Let Office connect to Online services. Additionally, go to Control Panel > Windows Credentials, remove the cached credentials.

Comment: I already disabled those settings using a GPO but unfortunately the issue still persists.

Comment: Did you ever get a solve for this?  Running into the same issue with a user here.  Have disabled the setting in question and removed credentials; user is still being prompted for login to "proxy server for officeclient.microsoft.com".